# Unexpected behaivour of xamarin android context menu

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xamarin.android

I've a xamarin android application.
When I type some text in edittext and long tap on it. It shows an unexpedted context menu like this one [image: here]

My styles.xml looks like

```
<resources>

  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:theme">@style/AppTheme.AppCompatLight</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.AppCompatLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF8B00</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#CF7100</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#CF7100</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#FF8B00</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FF8B00</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
  </style>
  
  <style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  </style>

  <style name="linkForground">
    <item name="android:color">#00A4E3</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Text input is

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/ui_email_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ui_address_text_input_layout">
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/etUIEmail"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:ems="15"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This issue is happening on my phone. I've tested it on another phone where it just set the background of all the activities like it did for CUT and SHARE.
Help is needed to solve this issue

Comment: I made a basic demo with your posted codes, but failed to reproduce the problem. Could you please post more detailed codes? or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo

Comment: I don't know which change has the effect but I'm not getting this anymore

Comment: Glad to hear that you have resolved this issue, but could you please post the answer so that someone else who have encounter the problem can see the answer? :)